# ng-show only for admin and kp in meanjs?

Tags: html, meanjs

In `view.article.view.html` i want to show html tag only if the authenticated user is `admin or kp`. I tried to do so like below, but it did not work.

```
<p ng-show="vm.authentication.user.roles=='admin', 'kp'">show only for admin and kp </p>
```

- And I can able to shows the html tag if i have used single role like :- `ng-show="vm.authentication.user.roles=='admin'" and ng-show="vm.authentication.user.roles=='kp'"`
- but i am looking to use two roles, how can I do this please help us thanks...

Comment: `ng-show="vm.authentication.user.roles=='admin' || vm.authentication.user.roles=='kp'"`

Comment: If you can write it as an answer i will tick mark it. thanks

Comment: No, that's fine. Glad to help :)